# Go returns error when trying to append structure of the same type

Tags: go, yaml

I am getting error trying to merge two structures using append function:

```
./test.go:33:18: cannot use configs (type MapUsers) as type struct { Userarn string "yaml:\"userarn\""; Username string "yaml:\"username\""; Groups []string "yaml:\"groups\"" } in append
```

Here is the code.

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
  "io/ioutil"
  "os"
)



type MapUsers []struct {
    Userarn  string
    Username string
    Groups   []string 
}


func main() {
    filename := os.Args[1]
    var configs MapUsers

    source, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(source, &configs)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    configs = append(configs, configs)
    fmt.Printf("Value: %#v\n", configs)


}
```

Here is the data:

```
- userarn: "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
  username: "bbbbbbbbbb"
  groups:
    - "ccccccccccc"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `test = append(configs, configs...)`

Answer (score 2):

Your append syntax seems wrong. It should be like this.

`configs=append(configs,test)`

`append` function a new slice including your new struct, so you take it and put to your old `configs` variable.

From golang tour: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/15

EDIT after comment:

I didn't realize that your `configs` was not a slice. It should be as follows:

`var configs []MapUsers`

There should be a `[]` before the type to show that it's a slice.

Comment: Thank you. But it changes nothing. Error is identical:   cannot use test (type MapUsers) as type struct....

Comment: now I am getting the following:  cannot unmarshal !!map into main.MapUsers

Comment: I see that you are not adding my changes to your code. Append line is still wrong and configs is still not a slice. Please take a look at tutorials on the internet and start with something easier like integers to learn how slices work. http://ghodss.com/2014/the-right-way-to-handle-yaml-in-golang/

Comment: Welcome to the world of Go :)